# Firewall rules on a hosting (dedicated server)

Tags: iptables, web-server

I am on Linux Debian Jessie 8.4.

I have set up a web server. It seems to run fine.

I'm just wondering, if I need the following firewall rules are ok for HTTP(S) server to be running fine.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

The server is behind a router. Port 22 is not forwarded. 10100 is used for passive FTP

Thank you.

Comment: An individual rule is nearly meaningless by itself. Can you please post your entire iptables rule set?

Comment: @EEAA OK, you shall have it

Comment: Allowing the whole world to connect to your SSH may not be the smartest thing to do, but you have reasons to do so. What's port 10100 used for?

Comment: @TeunVink The server is behind a router. Port 22 is not forwarded. 10100 is used for passive FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you want to block everything that isn't explicitly allowed and should add a final rule after what you already have :

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```